# Magento 2 : How to override a source model?

Tags: magento2, source-model, override-model

I am trying to override/rewrite `Magento\Fedex\Model\Source\Generic` by using preference but to no avail.

Is there some other way that is used to override source models in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via plugin. 
First of all you must create di.xml

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Fedex\Model\Source\Generic">
      <plugin name="your_plugin_name" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin\GenericPlugin" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then you must create GenericPlugin.php and use after method.

```
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Plugin;

class GenericPlugin
{
    public function afterToOptionArray(\Magento\Fedex\Model\Source\Generic $subject, $result)
    {
        // here you change the result
        return $anotherResult;
    }
}
```

More information [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

Comment: Thankyou for reply.
The thing is that I have to pass different params to __construct that current params being sent. So I think that would not be possible with plugin

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to inject, and why? @Vivek Kumar